# How do you create a generic method in a class?

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, syntax

I am really trying to follow the DRY principle.  I have a sub that looks like this?

```
Private Sub DoSupplyModel

        OutputLine("ITEM SUMMARIES")
        Dim ItemSumms As New SupplyModel.ItemSummaries(_currentSupplyModel, _excelRows)
        ItemSumms.FillRows()
        OutputLine("")

        OutputLine("NUMBERED INVENTORIES")
        Dim numInvs As New SupplyModel.NumberedInventories(_currentSupplyModel, _excelRows)
        numInvs.FillRows()
        OutputLine("")   

End Sub
```

I would like to collapse these into a single method using generics.  For the record, ItemSummaries and NumberedInventories are both derived from the same base class DataBuilderBase.

I can't figure out the syntax that will allow me to do ItemSumms.FillRows and numInvs.FillRows in the method.

FillRows is declared as `Public Overridable Sub FillRows` in the base class.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Here is my end result

```
Private Sub DoSupplyModels()

    DoSupplyModelType("ITEM SUMMARIES",New DataBlocks(_currentSupplyModel,_excelRows)
    DoSupplyModelType("DATA BLOCKS",New DataBlocks(_currentSupplyModel,_excelRows)

End Sub

Private Sub DoSupplyModelType(ByVal outputDescription As String, ByVal type As DataBuilderBase)
    OutputLine(outputDescription)
    type.FillRows()
    OutputLine("")
End Sub
```

But to answer my own question...I could have done this...

```
Private Sub DoSupplyModels()

    DoSupplyModelType(Of Projections)("ITEM SUMMARIES")
    DoSupplyModelType(Of DataBlocks)("DATA BLOCKS")

End Sub

Private Sub DoSupplyModelType(Of T as DataBuilderBase)(ByVal outputDescription As String, ByVal type As T)
    OutputLine(outputDescription)
    Dim type as New DataBuilderBase (_currentSupplyModel,_excelRows)
    type.FillRows()
    OutputLine("")
End Sub
```

Is that right?

Seth

Comment: Would a C# example help?

Comment: You want to change DoSupplyModel to receive either a `ItemSummaries` or a `NumberedInventories`? If so you can simply use the base class `DataBuilderBase` to receive as parameter type. You do not need a generic in that case.

Comment: C# is fine...I can convert it if I don't get it...but I read c# pretty well.

Comment: smink...you are right...generics not needed in my example...but I would still like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you don't need generics to do what you want, but I will answer the technical question for completeness:

```
Private Sub MyMethod(Of T As DataBuilderBase)(ByVal instance As T)
    instance.FillRows()
End Sub
```

And then call the method by doing this:

```
MyMethod(Of ItemSummaries)(new SupplyModel.ItemSummaries(...))
```

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question in the right language.

Answer (score 1):

you can refactor to take advantage of the fact that the share a common base and use polymorphism:  (VB a bit rusty, you should get the idea)

you could have a method:

```
Private Sub FillAndOutput(textToOutput as String, filler as DataBuilderBase)
    OutputLine(string)        
    filler.FillRows()
    OutputLine("")
end sub
```

which you could call:

```
Private Sub DoSupplyModel
    FillAndOutput("ITEM SUMMARIES",New SupplyModel.ItemSummaries(_currentSupplyModel, _excelRows))
    FillAndOutput("NUMBERED INVENTORIES",New SupplyModel.NumberedInventories(_currentSupplyModel, _excelRows))        

End Sub
```

Comment: I think that's already true **FillRows is declared as Public Overridable Sub FillRows in the base class.**

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to specify that T will be a subclass of the base type that implements `FillRows` method.  In C# this would look like so

```
private void myFunction<T>( T someList ) where T : DataBuilderBase {
    someList.FillRows();
}
```

Found a VB.NET [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235246%28VS.80%29.aspx).

**EDIT** and Kevin is right, this would probably be handled better with polymorphism.

Comment: It is that where T : DataBuilderBase that I did not understand how to do.  (In other words how to constrain the generic type.)  In VB the syntax is   
Private Sub myFunction(Of T As DataBuilderBase)(ByVal someList As T).  THANKS A BILLION.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I don't think that refactoring to a generic function is justifiable, even at the expense of repeating yourself. You would have two options:

1. Refactor your code so that it allows for parameterless constructors and create a function at a higher level of inheritance that allows you to specify the arguments currently being passed to the constructor.
2. Use explicit reflection to instantiate the generic type and pass those arguments to the constructor.

Either of those options involves a non-trivial amount of work with very little gain (you're translating three lines of code into one).

However, to answer your question, VB.NET uses the `of` keyword to specify generic type arguments

```
Public Sub Foo(Of T)(argument as T)
   ...
End Sub
```

Comment: I am curious why you don't think this is justifiable?  Seth

Comment: @Seth: The cost of making it generic is too high compared with the benefits you'll see from it. The only reason you'd need to make it generic would be either to instantiate the generic type (which would mean you'd have to go through the trouble I listed in my anwer) or to return the generic type so that you could have a more fluent interface (I don't really see this being the case). The only portion that could be refactored out apart from these is the call to `FillRows`, and I just don't see the benefit in creating a new function that simply calls one other function with no logic.